# Cannot install the watchdog package

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, watchdog

I have recently updated the OS on my Pi to Raspbian Stretch and having problems setting up the watchdog. Namely when I try to download the package I get the following error message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install watchdog

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package watchdog is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'watchdog' has no installation candidate
```

Why can't apt-get find the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding this line to /etc/apt/sources.list:

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main

Comment: There is no need to add the repository from `Debian`. `watchdog` is also in the default `Raspbian` repository `deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi`. You are now mixing up both repositories with nearly same packets and with same packet names. This may give you difficulties in the future. It's unsure what packet `apt` selects.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.